# getting comatose working with authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, authlogic, blogs

I started using comatose to handle content on my site but am having problems using it with my existing authentication using a generic Authlogic config.

In the readme he sites an example for configuring it with Restful Authentication and I'm wondering how I would do the same within a general Authlogic setup?

```
    #environment.rb 
    Comatose.configure do |config|
      # Includes AuthenticationSystem in the ComatoseController
      config.includes << :authenticated_system
    end
```

http://github.com/darthapo/comatose

Comment: I would like it if it could just inherit the applcationcontoller but can't seem to get it to do that.

Comment: Well... i found a nice little work around, but i'd prefer if their were another way... the plugin was inheriting directly from ActionController::Base, i changed it to ApplicationController and now it works.  But i'd prefer a way to do inside my app as opposed to making the change in the plugin. ;-(  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to do it is moving the auth methods out into a module, and include that from both ApplicationController and comatose. Example:

Put your auth methods into user_sessions_helper:

```
module UserSessionsHelper
  module AuthMethods
    private 
      ...
    def require_user
      ...
```

Then include the module in your ApplicationController:

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     include UserSessionsHelper::AuthMethods
     ...
```

And finally in the comatose config as well (environment.rb):

```
Comatose.configure do |config|
  config.admin_includes << "UserSessionsHelper::AuthMethods"   
  config.admin_authorization = :require_user
end
```